# Help understanding a sentence from "The Screwtape Letters" by C. S. Lewis

Tags: meaning, comprehension

> The trouble about argument is that it moves the whole struggle onto the Enemy's own ground. He can argue too; whereas in really practical propaganda of the kind I am suggesting He has been shown for centuries to be greatly the inferior of Our Father Below.

The first sentence makes perfect sense, it says that arguing will make the "Enemy" more defensive(of that nature). The second part: " whereas in really practical propaganda of the kind I am suggesting He has been shown for centuries to be greatly inferior", does not make sense.

Comment: It's relatively intricate phrasing by modern standards. You'll find it easier to parse if you imagine *in really practical propaganda of the kind I am suggesting* being a "parenthetical" element (i.e. - think of it as being in brackets, like this one).

Comment: Ok, thanks @FumbleFingers. That helped a little, but what about when it transitions to say "He has been shown for centuries to be greatly inferior of Our Father Below." What you said makes sense, but then that part mucks it up a bit for me.

Comment: C. S. Lewis is known for the screwy way he tapes together letters.

Comment: Forget the parenthetical element, then you don't need to think about "transitions". You're just left with *[The Enemy] has been shown ... to be ... inferior*. What's problematic about that?

Comment: Ok that helps a lot, so what is it saying in relation to the rest of the sentence when it says, "whereas in really practical propaganda of the kind I am suggesting"?

Comment: @EthanLeyden *[The Enemy] has been shown ... to be ... inferior [in really practial propaganda]*. Screwtape is saying that God is inferior to the Devil when it comes to "really practical propaganda" (as opposed to rational argument). StoneyB makes the point clear.

Comment: The sentence is very poorly written.  Basically - it's babble.  You are wasting your time worrying about it much.

Comment: @JoeBlow OP has mistranscribed; once the omitted *the* is restored I see nothing wrong with this sentence--it's grammatical and intelligible, especially in context. Its philosophical and theological truth is another matter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the first part: Screwtape does not say that the Enemy will be more "defensive" but that the struggle will be carried on "terrain" where the Enemy is stronger. God (says Screwtape) has the advantage in rational argument.

But in "practical propaganda"—that is, appealing to irrational motives —God is inferior to the Devil. "Practical propaganda" is therefore what Screwtape is suggesting: he advises Wormwood not to try to persuade The Patient that materialism is "true" (an appeal to logic) but to make him believe that materialism is "strong, or stark, or courageous — that it is the philosophy of the future" (an appeal to emotion).

Answer (score -1):

"The trouble about argument is that it moves the whole struggle onto the Enemy's own ground. He can argue too; "
i.e. Logic and rationale find their source in God. Those are HIS tools. And if you use logic, then you are at an immediate disadvantage if you are trying to fight against Him.

"...whereas in really practical propaganda of the kind I am suggesting..." 
i.e. But in the art of creative embellishment (or outright lies)

"...He has been shown for centuries to be greatly the inferior of Our Father Below."
i.e. God is handicapped by His insistence on always being truthful.